# Instalar somente o app sem sobrescrever o banco sqlite que já está sendo usado

Tags: android, delphi, sqlite, firemonkey

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando Delphi Tokyo para Android.

Mas ao compilar sempre ele pega o banco de dados do *sqlite* e sobre escrever o 
que já está lá cheio de dados.

Como esse app vai para o cliente, gostaria de saber como faço pra atualizar somente o programa, sem sobrescrever o banco de dados atual, se precisar de alterações realizar elas normalmente (`If Not Exists`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se estás a copiar o ficheiro com o banco de dados do *sqlite* para o *android* através do menu `Project->Deployment`, tens lá uma opção **overwrite** que podes por para **never** e assim não sobrepores o ficheiro caso este já lá exista.